# How to execute JS after redirect in a controller (Rails)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Create**

```
if @image.save
    format.html { redirect_to vote_path(@image) }
    format.js { render :js => "my_function();" }
end
```

so I'd like to fire up a function after the redirect has happened, but this doesn't work. Are there any other methods I could try and could you suggest me any please?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the javascript supposed to do? Depending on the desired result, the answer can be different. For example if you just want to display a message, Rails has the built-in flash mechanism.

Comment: @p11y the funciton should `$("#share_window").show();`

Comment: You can just put it in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect and render are separate. If you want it to run JS after the redirect, you can put some in the view that the vote_path is using. If you only want it to run after the redirect and not on the page load, you can set a flash before you redirect, and then check for the flash in the view.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to create a view to `create.js.erb`, and it run JS:

Your controller:

```
if @image.save
  format.html { redirect_to vote_path(@image) }
  format.js { }
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#share_window").show();
```