# Redirect_to a part of a page that is initially collapsed, but with collapsed part opened?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `redirect_to` and need the user to be placed at the specific `anchor` (can do that much), but with the [collapsed](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp) portion of the page already opened up.

I tried

- giving an element inside the collapsable portion an id, then [redirecting to that id using `anchor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13791606/5783745), but that doesn't open the collapsed portion of the page, so the user doesn't see what they're supposed to, and they may get confused
- Running some javascript after the redirect, but it may [not be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25508051/5783745)

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by using a [session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4887409/5783745) variable (e.g. `collapse = 'show'`), accessing that in the view to append that value to the bootstrap `collapse` class so it looks like this when it should be collapsed `collapse`, and it should look like this when it should load the page **not** collapsed [`collapse show`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42688378/5783745)

This approach could be better if using query params for the action being redirected to (either way will work, but the second method won't clutter the user's session)